# How to group lines in file by two?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a text file like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

---

How can I group those lines to obtain an output like this:

```
a-b
b-c
c-d
d-e
e-f
f-g
```

---

I have to do this in shell (sh, csh, bash).

I have found this:

```
cat file | xargs -n2
```

but the last element of first group does not became the first of the second.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR!=1{print x"-"$0}{x=$0}' file
```

- `NR!=1` applies on all line, except the first one
- `print x"-"$0` print the values with dash between
- `x=$0` set `x` (for the next iteration)

Answer (score 5):

With POSIX `sed`:

```
sed '1{
  h
  d
}
H
x
s/\n/-/
' <file
```

or one-liner version:

```
sed -e '1{h;d' -e\} -e 'H;x;s/\n/-/' <file
```

Comment: I need the first letter of the second line to be the last in the first line...

Comment: Nice use of the hold space.

Comment: yeah, its fine.

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Answer (score 5):

```
paste -d- - ./infile <infile
```

^That would work really well, except that your input is off-by-one. So...

```
{ echo; cat <infile; } | paste -d- - ./infile | sed '1d;$d'
```

...would work, but maybe is too complicated...

Comment: Well, that's exactly the same came into my mind at first after mis-reading the OP requirement, but I decided to let `sed` do it alone.

Comment: @cuonglm - did i misread it?

Comment: No, I bet. But you need `sed 1d\;\$d` to correct it.

Comment: How about this variant? `sed '2~2p' infile | paste -d- - -`

Comment: @steeldriver - maybe, but i dunno what the tilde does.

Comment: Sorry - it's a GNU sed extension that adds a step to the address, so `2~2` addresses even lines only (which the `p` then duplicates)

Comment: @steeldriver... So... `n;p`...? Either way, you should do the answer - i'll vote for it *(but id rather vote for `n;p`)*...

Comment: Ah yes - didn't think of that one. Even better.

Comment: @steeldriver - youre not gonna do it? It was a good idea!

Comment: @Costas - that way you get `a-b\nc-d` and so on - it doesnt double them.

Comment: Now I see. `paste -d- <(head -n -1 input) <(tail -n +2 input)`

Comment: Or `paste -d- <( sed '$d' input.txt ) <( sed 1d input.txt )`.  Or `{ read ; paste -d- input.txt -; } < input.txt | sed '$d'`

Answer (score 2):

One more `sed`

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/-/p;s/-/\n/;D' <input
```

and can be modified (thanks to [mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/52934/mikeserv)):

```
sed -n 'N;y/\n/-/;P;y/-/\n/;D' <input
```

Comment: `y/-\n/\n-/` could replace both s/// maybe. If it did it would be quicker, portable for the \n use, and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

A pure bash version -

```
old=""; while read -r line ; do [[ -n "$old" ]] && echo   $old-$line;   old=$line; done  < input

a-b
b-c
c-d
d-e
e-f
f-g
```